# RxJS - Strange behavior when using fromEvent with switchMap

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an event emitter that emits events fairly quickly and sometimes multiple events are emitted in the same tick. When I create an observable from this emitter and use `switchMap` I get some strange behavior where `n` values go into `switchMap` but only 1 comes out. Here is some simplified code:

```
const e = new EventEmitter();


const s = fromEvent<ConfigurationUpdatePayload>(
  e,
  'updated'
).pipe(
  take(4),
  map(() => Math.random() > 0.3 ? 1 : 2),
  tap(v => console.log('pre', v)), //pre log
  switchMap(async (i) => [
    await Promise.resolve((i + 1) === 2),
    i
  ] as const),
  tap(v => console.log('post', v)), //post log
  filter(([f,]) => f),
  map(([, p]) => p)
);


s.subscribe(v => console.log('result', v));

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  e.emit('updated', 1);
  // await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000)); - if I uncomment this it works
}
```

Here I see `console.log('pre', v)` evaluated 4 times but `console.log('post', v)` only once. If I uncomment the sleep in the for loop, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this, this is a sync emission, you will end up with one event going through because when source observable emits, switchMap will unsubscribe/cancel inner observables which is a async promise in your case.

it is similar to the following scenario

```
const e=new Subject();
e.pipe(switchMap(e=>timer(0).pipe(mapTo(e)))).subscribe(console.log)

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  e.next('updated');
}
```

you will end up getting only one 'update'. One of the solution here is to replace `switchMap` with `mergeMap`.

It is really an expected behavior for `switchMap` where how many emission you get depends on frequency of source emission vs inner observable emission.